# Rotating a point vs rotating coordinate system

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

Let's suppose we rotate point $P$ by angle $\alpha$ to obtain point $P'$. How to prove that coordinates of point $P$ are $P'$ in the new coordinate system realized by rotating our coordinate axes by $-\alpha$? Is it something that needs to be proven? Or can we just accept it because it's obvious?

While the formula for rotating a point around origin is simple, and the proof does take all  four quadrants of coordinate system into account, [the proof presented here](http://archive.today/YwlKv) of the effect rotating the axes has on point coordinates works only for the first quadrant (and only if we don't cross point $P$ while move the $X$ axis - meaning this proof is valid only if the angle between $|OP|$ and $X$ is greater than $\alpha$ on the figure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Active rotation of the vector $x = \vec{OP}$ to a new vector $x'$:
$$
x' = A x
$$
where $A$ is the matrix of the rotation.

We want to get the same new coordinates $x_i'$ by a change of point of view, the vector stays the same, by a linear transformation of the coordinate system, where the base vectors $e_i$
get transformed into new base vectors $e_i'$ according to
$$
e_i' = B e_i
$$
for $i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$.

\begin{align}
\underbrace{A^{-1} x'}_{(4)} = x
&= \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i e_i}_{(1)}
\\
&=^! \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i' e_i'}_{(2)}
= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i' B e_i
= \sum_{i=1}^n B x_i' e_i
= B \sum_{i=1}^n x_i' e_i
= \underbrace{B x'}_{(3)}
\end{align}
which leads to $B = A^{-1}$.

$(1)$ vector $x$ as linear combination of original base vectors, having coordinates $x_i$

$(2)$ the same vector $x$ expressed as linear combination of new base vectors, having new coordinates $x_i'$

$(3)$ the effect of $B$ (interpreted as active transformation within the old coordinate system) is $B x' = x$

$(4)$ this should be consistent with the active transformation $A x = x'$

Comment: How did you get from $\sum_i x_i e_i'$ to $\sum_j a^T_{ij} b_{jk}^{-1} = \delta_{ik}$? What are $\delta_{ik}$ and $E$?

Comment: You mean $E$ is identity matrix?

Comment: According to your equality ($\underbrace{\sum_j x_j' e_j}_{\tiny\mbox{new coords,old system}} 
= \sum_j \sum_i a_{ji} x_i \sum_k b_{jk}^{-1}e_k'$), it follows that $x_{j}'e_{j} = \sum_k b_{jk}^{-1}e_k'$. Could you clarify how's that possible? $e_{k}$ and $e_{j}$ are vectors, right? Please correct your answer if necessary.

Comment: I mean $e_{k}'$ and $e_{j}$. If you believe it's correct, let me know.

Comment: @user4205580 I found two mistakes: the invariant and the base change in components seem to have been wrong. And it got simpler.

Comment: It is the old vector (that arrow) expressed via new base vectors, this will determine the new coordinates. We are trying to find out how to choose the new base vectors, thus $B$. The result is how to choose $B$ in terms of $A$.